# How to add these elements in bulk?

Tags: javascript

I need to add these elements:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
    <input class="inputone" id="optionsRadios1text" type="text">
  </label>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="childs"></div>
```

Is there a way to do this without using multiple appendChild functions ?

Comment: Like put the markup in a string and inject it?

Comment: You only need one `appendChild`, something like `document.getElementById('childs').appendChild(document.querySelector('.checkbox'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have this markup in DOM yet, just this is enough:

```
var html = "<div class='checkbox'>"+
"  <label>"+
"    <input type='checkbox' name='optionsRadios' id='optionsRadios1' value='option1'>"+
"    <input class='inputone' id='optionsRadios1text' type='text'>"+
"  </label>"+
"</div>"

var  childs = document.getElementById('childs')

childs.innerHTML = childs.innerHTML + html
```

If you need to continuously add checkboxes to childs (better call it children really) you do not want to do that and want to do `appendChild(checkbox)` 
you can add hidden tag somewhere on the page and use it. See markup:

```
<div id='cb' class="checkbox" style='display:none'>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
    <input class="inputone" id="optionsRadios1text" type="text">
  </label>
</div>
<div id="children">content</div>
<button id='btn'>add</button>
```

and code:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
, children = document.getElementById('children')
, cb = document.getElementById('cb')

btn.addEventListener('click', add)

function add() {
    var n = cb.cloneNode(true)
    n.style.display = '';   
    children.appendChild(n)
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/jjumza62/)

Be advised though, you are using `id` attribute in your "template" thus after multiple inserts you are going to have multiple elements with the same id.
You probably need to update that and/or use only `name` attribute.

Otherwise you can query DOM for that child node and inset it with one appendChild call.

Comment: just tryed but it replace all the other elements in the <div id="childs"></div>

Comment: At first is empty, but then not.

Comment: It resets all the values :(

Comment: I added fiddle with full example. see updated answer

Comment: Now it works :D.
Then is a problem if there are multiple element with the same id ?

Comment: Yes, obviously you are going to get data from those checkboxes later on, and IDs has to be unique in the document

Comment: and if I use only the "name" attribute to get data, is there some type of problem ?

Comment: names don't have to be unique. but if you POST it to the server, multiple elements with the same will be either last one posted or, or you may change name to 'something[]' and it will produce an array. I'd recommend you to go  and read what MDN says about DOM and forms.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call multiple `appendChild()` functions.

`document.getElementById('childs').appendChild(document.querySelector('.checkbox‌​'));`

Comment: I already have multiple .checkbox elements but I just tryed and it doesn't work. Why ?

Comment: @xRobot - Well, that's different, if you have multiple `.checkbox` elements you should say so, as that would require iteration and multiple `appendChild`